# A question (more like three) about a topological space of ordinals.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I've been struggling with these for a while now, if anyone is willing to offer a hint I'll be more than grateful.

Given an ordinal $\varepsilon$, consider the topological space $L_{\varepsilon}$ whose points are the ordinals below $\varepsilon$ and whose topology is generated by the open intervals of the form 
$$
(\alpha,\beta)=\{\gamma < \varepsilon \, :\, \alpha < \gamma < \beta \}.
$$

(a.) Determine the ordinals $\varepsilon$ for which $L_{\varepsilon}$ has the property that any two closed sets of cardinality $|\varepsilon|$ are homeomorphic.

(b.) Determine the ordinals $\varepsilon$ for which $L_{\varepsilon}$ is countably compact (that is, each countable cover of $L_{\varepsilon}$ has a finite subcover).

(c.) Suppose $\varepsilon$ is a cardinal. Determine the supremum among the cardinals $\lambda < \varepsilon$ such that any intersection of less than $\lambda$ closed sets of cardinality $\varepsilon$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINTS: (I don’t like using $\epsilon$ for an arbitrary ordinal, so I’ve changed the notation slightly. I’m also dealing only with infinite ordinals, since the finite case is completely straightforward.) I would start with (b), which I think is the easiest, and do (a) last.

- (a) Suppose that $\alpha$ is an ordinal, and let $\kappa=|\alpha|$. Show first that if $\alpha=\kappa$, then any two closed subsets of $L_\alpha$ of cardinality $\kappa$ are homeomorphic. (In particular, they’re all homeomorphic to $L_\alpha$.) Then show that $L_\alpha$ is compact iff $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal. Use this to show that if $\alpha>\kappa$, then $[0,\kappa]$ is a compact subset of $L_\alpha$ of cardinality $\kappa$. If $\alpha>\kappa$ is a limit ordinal, however, $L_\alpha$ is a non-compact subset of $L_\alpha$ of cardinality $\kappa$, so it only remains to consider the case in which $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal. There is a unique successor ordinal $\beta$ such that $\alpha=\kappa+\beta$, where the addition here is ordinal addition. Show that if $\beta<\kappa$, then $L_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of $L_\kappa$ and $L_\beta$, which in turn is homeomorphic to $L_\kappa$; use the fact that $\beta+\kappa=\kappa$ (again an ordinal sum). Finally, to handle the case $\beta>\kappa$, answer the following question: is $[0,\kappa+\kappa]$ homeomorphic to $[0,\kappa]$ (where $\kappa+\kappa$ is the ordinal sum)?
- (b) If $\operatorname{cf}\alpha=\omega$, find an open cover of $L_\alpha$ with no finite subcover. (Here $\operatorname{cf}\alpha$ is the cofinality of $\alpha$.) What happens if $\operatorname{cf}\alpha=1$? If $\operatorname{cf}\alpha>\omega$?
- (c) Let $\kappa$ be the cardinal. Show that if $\lambda<\operatorname{cf}\kappa$, and $C_\xi$ is a closed subset of $L_\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$ for each $\xi<\lambda$, there is a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $L_\kappa$ such that $(\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1})\cap C_\xi\ne\varnothing$ for each $\xi<\lambda$, and use this sequence to find an ordinal in $\bigcap_{\xi<\lambda}C_\xi$. (If you get completely stuck, look at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_set#The_closed_unbounded_filter).) What happens if $\lambda\ge\operatorname{cf}\kappa$?